# How do I use special characters (ä, ö, ß) under Linux in c++? This code works just fine on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, non-ascii-characters

So when I am trying to stream in/out special characters on Linux, I get a "�" as a response.
I tried to set the locale to "de_DE.UTF-8", tried to set KDE's Konsole to German, but sadly this didn't solve the issue.

I am on Kubuntu 20.04 and I use VSCode as my IDE.

[image: Console screenshot]

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//creating variable to store character in
char character;

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");
    //system("locale");

    // getting the input from user
    cout << "Please enter a character that you would like to know the ASCII-Code, Octal value and the Hexadecimal value of: ";
    scanf(" %c", &character);

    // printing the character, ASCII-Code, Octal value and Hexadecimal value
    printf("\nThe ASCII-Code for the Character '%c' is: DEC=%d\n", character, character);
    printf("\nThe Octal value for the Character '%c' is: OCT=%o\n", character, character);
    printf("\nThe Hexadecimal value for the Character '%c' is: HEX=%x\n\n\n\n", character, character);

    //not letting Command Prompt close itself
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'stream'?  Do you mean you want to type them in at the console?  If so, try `wchar_t wc; std::wcin >> wc;`.

Comment: your terminal probably uses UTF-8 which for non ASCII characters uses multiple bytes, none of `ä`, `ö` and `ß` are ASCII characters. You need to read and write using strings instead of single characters

Comment: `ä` is UTF-8 `0xC3` `0xA4`  So you need to read two characters https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E4 Assuming your terminal is using UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, so if I understand this correctly, special characters aren't part of ASCII and because of that they don't fit inside a single Byte and that's why I need to use strings instead, gonna try that. Altough, I still don't understand why this exact code works on Windows but not on Linux...